# three.js add texture to JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, html, three.js

I've created a 3D model in Blender. Than I exported it with Three.js exporter and load it in JavaScript. Everything works fine except texture is not shown. I added texture in Blender as picture.

JSON file:

```
{
"normals":[0,-1,0,...]
"vertices":[-0.0101738,1.5,6.55678,-0.0101738,1.5,...]
"materials":[{
    "DbgIndex":0,
    "blending":1,
    "colorSpecular":[1,1,1],
    "opacity":1,
    "colorDiffuse":[0.8,0.554325,0.316799],
    "mapDiffuseWrap":["repeat","repeat"],
    "transparent":false,
    "wireframe":false,
    "DbgColor":15658734,
    "depthWrite":true,
    "specularCoef":50,
    "mapDiffuse":"parket.jpg",
    "mapDiffuseRepeat":[1,1],
    "visible":true,
    "mapDiffuseAnisotropy":1,
    "shading":"phong",
    "depthTest":true,
    "doubleSided":false,
    "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
    "DbgName":"Les"
},{
    "DbgIndex":1,
    "blending":1,
    "colorSpecular":[1,1,1],
    "opacity":1,
    "colorDiffuse":[0.287043,0.0523764,0.0102247],
    "transparent":false,
    "wireframe":false,
    "DbgColor":15597568,
    "depthWrite":true,
    "specularCoef":50,
    "visible":true,
    "shading":"phong",
    "depthTest":true,
    "doubleSided":false,
    "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
    "DbgName":"\u010crna"
},{
    "DbgIndex":2,
    "blending":1,
    "colorSpecular":[1,1,1],
    "opacity":1,
    "colorDiffuse":[0.8,0.136903,0.018619],
    "transparent":false,
    "wireframe":false,
    "DbgColor":60928,
    "depthWrite":true,
    "specularCoef":50,
    "visible":true,
    "shading":"phong",
    "depthTest":true,
    "doubleSided":false,
    "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
    "DbgName":"Rjava"
}],
"metadata":{
    "materials":3,
    "uvs":0,
    "generator":"io_three",
    "type":"Geometry",
    "vertices":276,
    "normals":109,
    "faces":241,
    "version":3
},
"faces":[35,22,0,1,2,0,0...]
"uvs":[]
```

}

JSON Loader:

```
                var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
                loader.load( 'samosteza.json', function ( geometry, material ) {
                    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
                    mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = 30;
                    mesh.translation = THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
                    mesh.translateY(-150);
                    scene.add( mesh )
                }, 'parket.jpg');
```

Anyone know how to display texture? I have my texture ('parket.jpg') in the same folder as index.html file.

**EDIT:**

I just found out that the texture is shown, but not propperly. I have wood texture and all i see is brown color. I tried to change the texture with different one but I always get one color on the object and not the full texture.

[image]

**Texture:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be this would help you ?

```
mesh.material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( src );
mesh.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

Comment: No, the result is still the same.

Comment: Based on documentation "https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/loaders/JSONLoader" there should not be third parameter... also it looks in documentation they have materials[0].. Can you please check the source again ?  Also where did you add the above 2 lines ?

Comment: also cross check your export from blender.. the sample json file looks different with what you have.. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/models/animated/monster/monster.js

Comment: I just found out that the texture is shown, but not propperly. I have wood texture and all i see is brown color. I tried to change the texture with different one but I always get one color on the object and not the full texture.

Comment: You can try to use the sample json provided in threejs community with their texture in your code..  To see how its colors are appearing.. If it is still the case then may be it could be an issue of lights or material replacements in other parts of the code.. please provide the working sample so we can help you out..